# Is there an arXiv-like electronic archive used by the remote sensing community?

Tags: remote-sensing, publishing, research, academic

Mathematicians, physicists, and (theoretical) computer scientists use [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/) extensively to share their preprints. Indeed, one could say that it's the established way to share one's research.

Is there a similar preprint service that's used by remote sensing, GIS, and related communities?

A related question: [Preprint services other than arXiv (for other fields)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84/preprint-services-other-than-arxiv-for-other-fields) on Academia.SE.

Comment: I have seen quite a lot of deep learning applied to remote sensing papers on arxiv recently, a trend I would expect to grow. Interesting question, though.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that too. However, we just submitted a paper that doesn't make use of deep learning and other advanced ML machinery (so I guess that would make us the odd one out on arXiv) and we'd like to make the preprint available via an established preprint service.

Comment: You should start a trend. I would love to see more remote sensing related things on arXiv, whether or not they use deep learning.

Comment: A lot of my searches for remote sensing related things end up at Taylor and Francis online, http://www.tandfonline.com/action/doSearch?AllField=remote+sensing. Sorry, I'm not being very helpful.